# Remove 'key', 'value' keywords when List<KeyValuePair> is serialized to Json?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a list to which I am adding elements as shown,

```
foreach (int item in _elementList)
            {
                _deletionBody.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>("ID", item));
            }
```

When I Serialize it to json,     `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_deletionBody)`

I am getting

```
[{"Key":"ID","Value":8000},{"Key":"ID","Value":8001}]
```

But the format I need is

```
[{"ID":8000},{"ID":8001}]
```

How do I get in the above format? Or Is there  a better way of doing it?

Comment: Why are you using `KeyValuePair` in the first place? That's basically for the items in a `Dictionary`. Why not add items with an `ID` property and then you'll get the format you want?

Comment: The better way is to create `Dictionary` instead of `List` or you can create a `ViewModel`

Comment: Thanks; Never thought of creating a model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what you provided, it looks like when you serialize this list using JsonConvert.SerializeObject, it's giving you a JSON array where each element is an object with two properties: "Key" and "Value".

To get the output format you're looking for, you can modify your code to create objects with just the "ID" property instead of using key-value pairs. Here's an example of that:

```
List<object> deletionBody = new List<object>();
foreach (int item in _elementList)
{
    deletionBody.Add(new { ID = item });
}
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(deletionBody);
```

This will create a list of objects with a single "ID" property, and when you serialize it using JsonConvert.SerializeObject, it should give you the output format you're looking for.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any foreach loop at all, just use this code:

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_elementList.Select(item => new { ID = item }));
```

Answer (score 0):

The below should solve this. It creates an anonymous object with the structure you are after then serializes that

```
        var list = new List<KeyValuePair<string, int>>();

        list.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>("ID", 8001));

        var toSerialize = list.Select(x => new { ID = x.Value });

        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(toSerialize);
```

Answer (score 0):

They don't match because your json represents a list of `KeyValuePairs`. The expected json represents a list of `Objects` with a `property` named `ID`.

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
}

var items = new List<SomeClass>()
{
    new SomeClass() { ID = 8000} ,
    new SomeClass() { ID = 8001} ,
};

string json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(items);
```

If you still need the key with the data you can just mark it with `[JsonIgnore]`. Take note that `JsonIgnore` exists in both `System.Text` and `Newtonsoft.Text` so be sure to reference accordingly.

```
[JsonIgnore]
public string Key { get; set; }
```